# How to install an apk through a server web link?

Tags: html, download

I have an apk located on a server, inside a folder, but when I call it through the path below.

It tries to install it on the mobile with the following extension: file.apk.html

`<a href="http://server/folder/file.apk" download> Download here </a>`

Why does the final html extension appear?

Comment: what is the response `content-type`?

Comment: I need to access that web server from my mobile device and when I click on the download, install or apk link. But that doesn't happen. When you click instead of installing the apk, the file has the final extension file.apk.html.

Comment: right - but what's its headers show?